Populate a combox from another worksheet based on a specific grade
Here is my issue:
I have an Excel worksheet(Name is "Form") with a combo-box named "dept".
On another worksheet named "enrollment_details" contains grades A - F in Col "L" and course description in column "K" and Subject in column "H".
I am a newbie to this and when a checkox is checked, the combox parses the "enrollment_details" worksheet and looks at column "L"(grades) for a grade of "F" only and populates the combo-box with data on Column "K" - course description and data in column "H" - Subject.
Here is what I have so far:
dept.List = Worksheets("enrollment_details").Range("L2:L57").Value - The combo-box only shows the grades.
and
code under the checkbox named "dept" to enable the combo-box:
Private Sub read_check_Click()
If read_check = True Then

    dept.Visible = True
    
    dept.List = Worksheets("enrollment_details").Range("L2:L57").Value

The combo-box only shows the grades and nothing else.
I am expecting to see the following in the combo-box:

Course description and subject based on the "F" grade only.

Be advised that there can be other "F" grades attached to other courses as well.


Any guidance is appreciated.
Thank you very much
Dion
<>
